# reflect bug in module, java 17

Tags: java-17

I write a framwork dependecies for projects which use **java 17**.

And recently I use the framework in a project which use **java 17**. I need to use reflect to create beans for a interface automatic.

So I write a `ClazzUtil` class in framework, it has a method to get all the classes under the package where the parameter class is located. like this:

```java
public static List<String> getAllImplClassesByInterface(Class c) {
        List<String> returnClassList = new ArrayList<>();
 
        if (c.isInterface()) {
            String packageName = c.getPackage().getName();
            // System.out.println(packageName);
            try {
                List<Class<?>> allClass = getClassList(packageName, true, null);
                for (int i = 0; i < allClass.size(); i++) {

                    if (c.isAssignableFrom(allClass.get(i))) {
                        if (!c.equals(allClass.get(i))) {// 本身加不进去
                            Class clazz = allClass.get(i);
                            if (clazz.getAnnotation(Deprecated.class) != null) {
                                continue;
                            }
//                            String cs = allClass.get(i).toString();
//                            returnClassList.add(cs.substring(cs.indexOf("class ") + 6));
                            returnClassList.add(clazz.getName());
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return returnClassList;
}
```

Then I use it in my business project, and worked for month. But today, the util class return empty list without code change.

I find the interface and the sub class have different module after debug. Then I move the util class to business project.

It work again, amazing!

But I don't know why. Someone can explain this ?

Comment: This code is unnecessarily complicated. What it does, is `if(c.isInterface()) for(Class<?> found: getClassList(c.getPackage().getName(), true, null)) if(found != c && c.isAssignableFrom(found) && !found.isAnnotationPresent(Deprecated.class)) returnClassList.add(found.getName());` Besides that, it’s the `getClassList` method which is searching for classes in a package and appears to break with your module setup. But when all implementation classes are supposed to be within the same package anyway, why not use a `sealed` interface? Then, you can simply use `c.getPermittedSubclasses()`…

Comment: Please use an [enhanced for loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html). I was asking myself "where do we need to use the index in your code?".

Comment: use the index in code is a problem, but it's small. I will add edit the question again with all util code